# back button in master detail page xamarin forms prism

Tags: xamarin, prism, master-detail

Im using prism with my xamarin forms application. i use master detail with the exact structure that you used but when i change detail page my back button wont work and when i click on back button in android it just close the app. and also the back button in toolbar wont show either. how can i fix this?
this picture belongs to time that i've changed the detail page that you can see there is no back button there

```
Version with issue: 7.0.0.396
Xamarin.Forms version: 3.0.0.482510
IDE: VS 15.7.1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vl2M.png)

Comment: The back button comes only if you have navigated to a page.
Also need more code to help you out.

Comment: worked : 
await navigationService.NavigateAsync("Nav/Main/MySosRequests");